An integral equation involving bivariate Fourier transform
I was recently trying to solve one PDE, and in doing so I stumbled upon the following integral equation which I cannot aproach: find $\varphi$ such that
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} \sin(k a) \, e^{i w s} \, \varphi(k, w) \, dw \, dk = 1
\quad \text{for all} \quad a < 0 \quad \text{and} \quad s \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
I am unsure whether the solution exists or not and I have no idea how to approach this.
P.S. Allowing $\varphi(k, w)$ to be a measure is okay for my needs. I tried solving the equation in $\delta$-measures, but I didn't know what to to with the $\sin$ integral.

$\varphi(k,w)=-\frac{2}{\pi k}\delta(w)$ is a solution, but I don't know whether it is unique.
